# how do i remove kitchen sink drainer basket without a visible lock nut?

Tags: kitchens, sink

my kitchen drainer basket is made of plastic without the usual lock nut. i could not remove it. 
[image: this is the type of kitchen drain installed in my sink][image: side view][image: view as seen underneath. the yellow mark seem to be lock nut which is difficult to remove because it stucked]

Answer (score 2):

The **entire lower plastic portion** is the locknut.

Have a helper hold the strainer in place from above using a *strainer wrench* (it's a thing, sometimes called a *spud wrench*), or by jamming the handles of channellock pliers into it, while you get under there and unscrew the whole plastic body from the strainer (turn CCW if looking up at it from below).

Answer (score 1):

I just used a small flathead screwdriver and a hammer to cut the little plastic fins down on the inside and the plastic cone fell off. You can see the plastic fins when you look down the drain and turn the plastic cone.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.